# What does "Result Column? 'In Sector' Cannot be checked with participant" mean?

Tags: custom-fields, profile

Im trying to create a profile form that connects to a speaker - participant profile for event hosts to review speakers. I created a custom field set and now and trying to put the questions into the profile form.

I want the results to be displayed only to people with permission as well as the form. When I edit the form and indicate that it is visible ONLY to "User and Admin" then it gives me the error attached.

How do I deal with this?

[image: Screenshot_of_participant_custom_field]

[image: error-message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two fields `Searchable?` and `Results Column?` that make sense only for Public Pages and contact profile.

The field `Searchable ?` should be automatically unchecked when setting the visibility to "User and User Admin Only". When testing in http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org in doesn't seems to be possible to even check them in a participant profile context.

Anyway, you might be able to submit the form by doing :

- change visibility to `Public Pages`
- uncheck `Searchable?` and `Results Column?`
- change visibility back to `User and User Admin Only`

If that doesn't work, i suggest you udpate your CiviCRM to latest version.